# How to merge 2 outputs array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a beginer in PHP programming, i want to ask for my problem here.

Before, i get the PHP scripts from: https://github.com/VosCast/SHOUTcast-PHP-Stats

This is the code, how i get the array:

```
require_once 'vc_shoutcast.class.php'; // get stats
require_once 'vc_shoutcast_json_relay.class.php'; // produce json

$lists = array(
    array(
        'host'  => 'host.net',
        'port'  => '9898'
    ),
    array(
        'host'  => 'host.net', 
        'port' => '8787'
    )
);

$i = 1;
foreach ($lists as $list => $radio) {
    $vc_shoutcast = new vc_shoutcast( $radio['host'], $radio['port'], false );
    $vc_shoutcast_json_relay = new vc_shoutcast_json_relay( $vc_shoutcast, 1, $cache = './stats_' . $i . '.json' );
    $vc_shoutcast_json_relay->run( 'both' );
$i++;
}
```

This is the vc_shoutcast_json_relay.class.php ( $vc_shoutcast_json_relay->run( 'both' ); ) code:

```
foreach ($vars as $value) {
    $data[$value] = $this->vc_shoutcast->$value;
}

var_dump( $data );
```

From the code above, I'll get two outputs array, like this:

```
Array(
     [currentlisteners] => 2,
     [maxlisteners] => 3,
     [songtitle] => Some song title 2
)

Array(
    [currentlisteners] => 12,
    [maxlisteners] => 13,
    [songtitle] => Some song title 2
)
```

How do I merge two arrays into one array become:

```
Array(
   [0] => (
        [currentlisteners] => 2,
        [maxlisteners] => 3,
        [songtitle] => Some song title 2
   ),

   [1] => (
       [currentlisteners] => 12,
       [maxlisteners] => 13,
       [songtitle] => Some song title 2
   )
)
```

I know, i can merge 2 arrays with array_merge( $data ) or with something similiar functions, but it isn't works.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you getting two arrays with the first code block? There's just one array `$data`.

Comment: Your arrays aren't merged, they're nested. `array($data1, $data2)`.

Comment: Do you run foreach twice to get 2 arrays ?

Comment: do you even [rtfm](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) bro?

Comment: I'm sorry, Thanks for your comments all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way is to just create a new one with your existing arrays as the values:

```
$newArray = array($array1, $array2);
```

This is the same as this:

```
$newArray = array();
array_push($newArray, $array1);
array_push($newArray, $array2);
```

Or this:

```
$newArray = array();
$newArray[] = $array1;
$newArray[] = $array2;
```

Depending on your code, you might prefer to add your data to the main array using one of the last two methods as you go along, rather than trying to create the whole thing in one go at the end.